# How to export the Calc Files data to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, openoffice-calc

In my ASP.Net Application , there is a place were people can import excel files into the server to extract some information and put them in an Sql Server database. Now, the company have change Microsoft Office to OpenOffice, so there is no more Excel files, it is Calc Files.

so, I need the code to export the Calc Files data to server.

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly do you need to do. Please clarify your question. The title conflicts with your description.

Comment: @amr check now i have changed the title

Comment: Thanks for the update, but still I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Export the Calc file to what format exactly?

Comment: @amr to read the contents in open office in asp net like what we do in exactly in excel.i need it in open office calc

Comment: Hi I need import OpenOffice Calc files to database can anyone tell me how to do this thank you